# C++ - Create Tree rekursively with map

Tags: c++, tree

I would like to create a tree where each node represents a single charakter, the leaf-nodes represent the string created by the chars which lead up to this leaf-node. My approach (maybe the class names are a bit missleading, this is just a quick prototype, Foo is the Base-class, Bar is a node and BarBar a leaf-node):

```
class Foo{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class BarBar : public Foo {
public:
    BarBar(int mData) : data(mData){};
    int data;

    void print(){
        cout << data << endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    map<char,Foo*> ptr;
    void insert(char c, Foo* f){
        ptr.insert(pair<char,Foo*>(c,f));
    }
    void procStr(char* str, int dat){
        if(str[0] != '\0'){
            Bar b;
            insert(str[0],b); //error "Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void insert(char, Foo *)'"
            str++;
            b.procStr(str,dat);
        } else {
            BarBar bar(dat);
            insert('^',bar); //error "Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void insert(char, Foo *)'"
        }
    }
    void print(){
        for (auto& kv : ptr){
            cout << kv.first << endl;
            kv.second->print();
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Bar root;
    root.procStr("Hello",42);
    root.print();
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output would be:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

But instead I get:

```
H
Ä
```

and the program crashes.

The program crashes at:

```
Foo& res = kv.second;
res.print(); //<<-- Program crashes
```

Comment: The `Foo&` references stored in the map all refer to local variables that are long gone when you try to print them.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
BarBar bar(dat);

            insert('^',bar); //error "Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void insert(char, Foo *)'"
```

Your function takes a Foo* but you are passing an instance (still a local instance at that, so even if you passed &bar it would be invalid by the time you use it).

A map is really not the right structure for this problem, look up order statistic trees, they provide ordering without sorting which is what you are after here. That is, an OS tree can store  'o', 'h' as readily as 'h', 'o'.